# One-to-one mapping in sql

Tags: sql

I need to make an one-to-one relationship between two tables, it means, each passenger can only reserve one seat on a flight.

I have 4 tables:

- `Passenger` : `passengerId(PK), passengerName, PassengerAddress`
- `Seat` : `seatId(PK), seatClass, flightId(Fk)`
- `Flight` : `flightId(PK), flightDate`
- `Reseveration` : `flight(PK), seatId(PK), passengerID(FK), reserveDate`

Comment: reservation primary key(flight, passengerID)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Passenger : passengerId(PK),passengerName,PassengerAddress
```

//in this table make passenger id primary key as passenger will be unique with their details

```
 Seat : seatId(PK), seatClass, flightId(Fk)
```

//in this table add a field say passenger id so that a passenger who is allotted in a flight will be maintained here eg passenger x in flight y. Also you can maintain a time for flight such that if a passenger wants to travel two times a day in a same flight

```
 Flight : flightId(PK), flightDate
```

//make flight id unique hare

```
 Reservation : flight(PK), seatId(PK), passengerID(FK), reservationDate
```

//this will be the final table reservation where you have all the details with no duplication.